# How to query a table referring to itself in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Customers` that contains the fields `customer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `referred_by`.

What I want to do is to display full name of the  customers who have been referred and the full name of the referrer.

For example I want something like this :

```
id | first_name | last_name | referred_by
1  |  first1    |  last1    |    NULL
2  |  first2    |  last2    |     1
3  |  first3    |  last3    |     2
```

the oupout should be:

```
customer's name   | referred by
first2 last2      | first1 last1
first3 last3      | first2 last2
```

Usually I would create a table called references and store the references there but I can't modify the database.

I imagine something like :

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS 'Customer''s Name', 
     CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS 'Referred By '
FROM customer
WHERE 'Customer''s Name'.refferedby = 'Referred By'.customerno;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join.

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(c1.firstname, ' ', c1.lastname) AS 'Customer''s Name', 
     CONCAT(c2.firstname, ' ', c2.lastname) AS 'Referred By '
FROM customer c1 join customer c2 = c1.id = c2.referred_by
```

Answer (score 3):

If the referred_by column contains an id value from the customer table, then it would be something like this:

```
select concat(c.firstname,' ',c.lastname) customer
     , concat(r.firstname,' ',r.lastname) referred_by_customer
from customer c
     left join customer r on r.customer_id = c.referred_by
```

Answer (score 0):

This join solution is almost what I wanted! The c2 and the c1 fields must be inverted and there is also a syntax error on your join so the correct query is :

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(c1.firstname, ' ', c1.lastname) AS 'Customer''s Name', 
     CONCAT(c2.firstname, ' ', c2.lastname) AS 'Referred By '
FROM customer c1 join customer c2 on c1.referredby = c2.customerno;
```

The solution with the left join give me also all the customers who are not referred too (which is useless for me, the aim of the query is to find the customers referred).

However I obtain the same result with :

```
 select concat(c.firstname,' ',c.lastname) 'Customer''s Name',
        concat(r.firstname,' ',r.lastname) 'Referred By ' 
 from customer c, customer r 
 where r.customerno = c.referredby;
```

The interesting thing is that I always thought that table aliases are used to minimize the writing and not to actually distinguish different call of the same table.

Is it the same query with a different writing or there is something I am missing?